# Missing JQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I am newbie in jquery, I have read many solutions in this website about datepicker, but I don't understand.

I have code in `Page_A`. `Page_A` load `Page_B` that contain datepicker.

I try to put Jquery in `Page_A` or `Page_B`. and it still missing.

Page_A :

```html
<div class="label-form">Cari Pegawai</div>
<input type="text" id="autocomplate" name="nama" class="form500" placeholder="Nama Pegawai" size="50"> 
<input type="button" class="button1" value="Cari" onClick="return getTabelPns();"/>
<div id="autotampil"></div>
```

Page_B :

```html
<input type="text" id="tgl" size="15" name="tgl" value="12/12/1940" />
```

Here my complete code : http://www.4shared.com/rar/avzmICydba/email2.html

i have included my JQuery. In that link, i include JQuery in Page_B. i try to access page_B directly and it work. But when i access page_B from page_A it is not work.

Thanks a lot for your help ..

Comment: Do you include jQuery before your datepicker library ?

Comment: Include jQuery UI to get Datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

i have included my JQuery. In that link, i include JQuery in Page_B. i try to access page_B directly and it work. But when i access page_B from page_A it is not work.

I put my complate code in this link :

Downlod Here : http://www.4shared.com/rar/avzmICydba/email2.html

Thanks a lot for your help